# Dealing with extra '/' in URL

Tags: php

So I have a custom made site that uses this type of input:

```
example.com/?id=4e2dc982
```

Or this would also work:

```
example.com/index.php?id=4e2dc982
```

But now I've started seeing hits in my log from GoogleBot trying to retrieve this for some reason:

```
example.com/index.php/?id=4e2dc982
```

The worse thing is that this actually works, it pulls the page with the right GET parameter, but because of the extra '/' all the links and references don't work. When it tries to load "image.jpg" instead of loading the proper "example.com/image.jpg" it tries to load "example.com/index.php/image.jpg". How do I best fix this? I know I could go back and replace every link to use absolute paths but that's silly. The link with an extra '/' shouldn't work in the first place.

**Update:**

I found the fix, but still don't know why this is even allowed. I went to:

```
http://ca1.php.net/manual-lookup.php?pattern=test
```

And tried to see if the following was possible, and sure enough it works:

```
http://ca1.php.net/manual-lookup.php/?pattern=test
```

But their page doesn't break. So I looked at it and found out why:

```
<base href="http://ca1.php.net/manual-lookup.php" />
```

So basically, ANY PHP script seems to accept an extra /, but if you didn't code all your links to have absolute paths, or use a base tag, your site will be screwed up whenever someone adds an extra '/'.

Comment: If google bot fetches that url - then there is such url somewhere on your page. So change it to a correct one.

Comment: "The worse thing is that this actually works" - can you make it _not_ work? Since this is a "custom made site", it will be hard for us to help you unless you show us some code. By default, I am pretty sure your index.php at your domain root won't respond to requests to `../index.php/..` so there is probably something custom you are doing wrong.

Comment: You can use `mod_rewrite` to fix this, but I agree that you should find where it's being referenced as Googlebot wouldn't visit that URL by chance... It follows links!

Comment: As usual `<base href=>` or `<link rel=canonical>`, else checking `PATH_INFO` and doing a redirect to the base URL.

Comment: There is NO reference anywhere to such a URL. In fact, GoogleBot is trying to access hundreds of links using the wrong URLs, and I have no idea why, it never used to do that. As for fixing it, yes it's custom PHP but how can I make this not work? I didn't even know a php file could be loaded with an extra '/' and still work.

Answer (score 1):

It must be linked from somewhere, which you need to figure out from where. You can use google site search to (i.e. site:yoursie) may be to figure out.
One suggestion for now is to use canonical tag
http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com.au/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html

Answer (score 0):

I think that one of the things you could actually do is getting the header or browser agent (although some browsers don't send this), you could possibly do it. Then if the header contains anything like Google, do not allow the bot to crawl the page, else redirect the user to the site.
Below is an example:

```
$browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
checkbrowser($browser); //Calls checkbrowser(); with the browser version.
function checkbrowser($analyze) {
    $searchwords = array("bot","google","crawler");

    $matches = array();
    $matchFound = preg_match_all(
                "/\b(" . implode($searchwords,"|") . ")\b/i", 
                $analyze, 
                $matches
        );

        if ($matchFound) {
            $words = array_unique($matches[0]);
            foreach($words as $word) {
            if($word == "bot") {
                echo "Sorry, bots are not allowed to crawl this specific page.";
                die(); //Terminate the script and leave the bot with that message so it cannot crawl.
            }
        }
    }

}
```

This is how I often do it, but I utilize this method for different things. You can modify the function by changing the `$searchwords` to something that fits you best.

Comment: I think robots.txt would be fine.